# How to represent geological time? (Boost, Date_time?)

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, gregorian-calendar

I'm trying to process timestep interval data.  The data is of two formats:

1) each interval is explicitly set (e.g., 1982-12-31, 1988-01-01T00:00:00);

or

2) a start date is set followed by offsets of seconds, minutes, hours, days, months, or years

I've been using a combination of `boost::gregorian::date` and `boost::posix_time::ptime` to manage this, and use the facilities to get nicely formatted strings.  However, I've now been presented with data that covers 1.9 million years, with each timestep being approximately 10 years. The start date is 0 and the last interval is 7e8.  Obviously, I've hit the limits.

Is there a way using Boost to represent such scale?  My searching has led to the conclusion 'no' in which case we'll just write our own class.

Comment: This is a typical computer tradeoff:  precision versus range vs memory consumed.   If I were you, I would use a struct/class that has int32 years since some origin (1950 is a popular one in many geophysical contexts) and a time_t or int or whatever which has seconds since the beginning of the year.

Comment: Ask a Ruby developer.

Comment: I don't know what the problem is. Can't you use a double? Usually, the seconds and minutes become less interesting when measuring in decades, but even that should not really be a problem: even at largest scale (7e8) a [`double` should leave significant digits to represent ~3s intervals.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0d628a07bfd19e2)

Comment: Can you give examples of "nicely formatted" inputs/outputs for dates or intervals that cover 1.9 million years? I genuinely don't know what that would look like. Do you really have 7-digit years, plus month and day: YYYYYYY-MM-DD?! I suspect you'd be better off writing your own class that delegates parsing/formatting to the libraries you're already using for 'regular dates', but switch to a different mode when things get geological. Using doubles as the underlying representation may work well (origin near 'now') as their precision characteristics probably match your non-linear requirements.

Comment: Fwiw, here are the algorithms you will need if you want to pretend the Gregorian calendar is valid over timescales like this: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_algorithms.html

Comment: @sehe -- Yes, I will use a double.  I was just wondering if there were Boost facilities that handle this since my class is already making use of boost::posix::ptime and boost::gregorian.

Comment: @duncan -- The case is simulating magma flow.  It starts at year 0 and each interval adds additional years until the year 7e8.  There are approximately 194k time steps.  I still need to display the year for certain data points but obviously month and day is irrelevant.

Comment: The wording of the output is quite important, because the Gregorian calendar counts actual days (the sun really comes up in the east, crosses the sky, and sets in the west). But scientific calculations over long periods of time invariably use days consisting of 86,400 atomic seconds. Because the rotation rate of Earth is gradually decreasing, this will lead to large differences over nearly a billion years. You should consult with the scientists performing the fundamental work to determine the proper name for the time scale they are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very interesting question. But reaching the limits of boost in this area requires careful thinking about the risk of going beyond the astronomical limits of today.

Calendars and dates are very relative:

- Posix time is defined as time elapsed from January 1st, 1970, not counting the leap seconds.  boost allows you to choose between the microsecond or the nanosecond resolution at build time.
- The gregorian calendar is defined since October 15th, 1582.  Note that before 1930, some countries used the gregorian calendar and some still the julian one, the transition resulting in some [interesting facts](http://www.history.com/news/6-things-you-may-not-know-about-the-gregorian-calendar), such as the absence of 13 september 1752 in England and America.
- Before it was the Julian calendar, defined by J.Caesar in 45 BC.  Note that while the format, the number of month and length of month is the same than in the gregorian calendar, there are 13 days of difference between both, that take into account accumulated differences over the years.
- before 45BC, was there the old roman calendar which had 355 days/year.
- And longer before, until begin of mankind there were certainly all sorts of other calendars.  But a days wasn't always 24 hours long. The variations of 1 to 3 microsecond per day of [the solar day](http://tycho.usno.navy.mil/leapsec.html) add up if you go in the millions of years. For instance,  600 millions of years ago, the averge length of the day was only 22 hours.

If you're working on both geological and narrow scales the easiest approach coud be to use a class or a union combining a `long long` (for geological scale in years BC) and `boost::gregorian::date` (for years AC, if you can afford the imprecision julian/gregorian). The nice formating would then be relatively easy to organize.

Alternatively you could consider use of [chrono](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/chrono/) with the longest integer type and a ratio indicating that you'r counting the years:

```
typedef chrono::duration<long long, ratio<31556926, 1>> duration_in_year;
duration_in_year d2(1900000); // 1,9M years
chrono::time_point<chrono::system_clock> t1 = chrono::system_clock::now() - d2;
```

but nice printout will not be so evident as with boost.  And you'll have to define your own clock class (The example above will work with 1,9Mio years but not much more, due to the parameters used to instantiate the `system_clock` class).

Comment: Thanks, Christophe.  This was helpful in providing considerations in designing a class that can handle both both narrow and large scale time.